# storing variables within foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Hi I currently have some PHP code which will put previously selected timeslots from checkboxes on a previous page into my database, but I'm not sure how to store each one in a variable before I do this, so that I can use them to list the appointment slot's in my e-mail function

At the moment when I try to insert '$key' to my e-mail function it only retains the last selected value...

My code on the first page reads:

```
<?php
for ($i=0;$i<=31;$i++){ while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n",
$myrow[0]);
}

echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='$displayTime2' onclick='KeepCount()'></td>";
echo "<td>$pagetime</td>"; ?>
```

My code at the moment is as follows:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $key; // show times selected on previous page
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO appointment(Patient_ID, Appointment_Date, Appointment_Time
                , Practice_ID, Appointment_ID)
                VALUES('$patid','$insertdate','$key','$pracid','$apptype')");   
}
?>
```

my mail function is as follows:

```
   $to = "$pemail";
   $subject = "Talking Teeth Check Up Booking Confrmation";
   $message = "Hello! This e-mail is to confirm your ".$appname." appointment has been
   booked for ".$insertdate. " at ".$key." at the ".$pracname." practice";
   $from = "talkingteethdentists@talkingteeth.co.uk";
   $headers = "From:" . $from;
   mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
   echo "Mail Sent.";
```

Comment: There are so many levels of wrong in this code...

Comment: please post your HTML code

Comment: Could you please write more details ? You are talking about email but I just mysql insert statement in the loop...

Comment: What is this I don't even

Comment: Don't put a mysql query within a for loop - it'll lock your table. Don't use mysql_query - use either PDO or MySQLi. Don't post data without cleaning your variables first (in this case, your $_POST array).

Comment: I am completely new to php and the only way I could get each time inserted way by putting my mysql query in the foreach loop

Comment: Carefull, your code is at risk of sql injection. You should validate/sanitanize your $_POST before doing any sql request

Comment: Hi Tim.  There are some issues with your code which make it hard to know where to begin.  But  can I give you a solution just to the issue that you know you have.  In your mail function instead of using the value of $key, use implode(' , ', array_keys($_POST));  The reason your code does not work as you expect is because each iteration through the loop the value of $key is rewritten, so after the loop has completed it contains the last value only.  Please take a look at arrays http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the comments above are right, let me help you out.

First off, you need to figure out which checkboxes were selected, so do some IF statements to figure that out on each of these inside of your `foreach` loop.

Try something like this:

```
<?php
$savedData = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
    $key = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
    echo($key. "<br>"); // show times selected on previous page
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO appointment(Patient_ID, Appointment_Date, Appointment_Time
                , Practice_ID, Appointment_ID)
                VALUES('$patid','$insertdate','$key','$pracid','$apptype')");   

    //To save the variables for later:
    $savedData[] = $key;
}
?>
```

And now you can access all of our KEYs with $savedData[0] .... $savedData[1] ... $savedData[2] .... etc....

So your email function might look like:

```
foreach($savedData as $time){
   $to = "$pemail";
   $subject = "Talking Teeth Check Up Booking Confirmation"; //mis-spelled confirmation =)
   $message = "Hello! This e-mail is to confirm your ".$appname." appointment has been
   booked for ".$insertdate. " at ".$time." at the ".$pracname." practice";
   $from = "talkingteethdentists@talkingteeth.co.uk";
   $headers = "From:" . $from;
   mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
   echo "Mail Sent.";
}
```

So this will send out an email for each piece inside `$savedData` - if that truly is the intent.

Comment: These are checkboxes, so the value is typically `ON` or `OFF`.  The checkbox is probably named in some way to indicate the date.

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise good call, didn't see the checkbox note.  Let me edit.

Comment: @Shackrock thank you very much, I have modified it slightly so that it only sends 1 e-mail containing all of the selected times, thank you for all of your responses - they're greatly appreciated :-)